# if function getValue() on null return nothing

Tags: 8, entities

I looked around, but am not exactly sure how to ask this question.

Is there a means of not erroring out on "function getValue() on null". Basically I'd like to return nothing and move on if getValue is being called on something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a field is empty or not before asking for `getValue()` with:

```
if (!$entity->get('field_name')->isEmpty()) {
  $value = $entity->get('field_name')->getValue();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this within an array so something like this. Node::create([
           'field_supervisor_uid' => $user->get('field_supervisor')->first()->getValue()['target_id'],])->save();

Comment: Nevermind dumb question. Just handled it as a variable and then passed it in...

Comment: The problem is `->first()->getValue()` is going to error because you're accessing something that does not exist